# how to fix an object at either 90degree or 0 degree

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanical, energy, joining

my problem is i donot know how to let the blue colored object be fixed at either 0 or 90 degree.
i dnot want to be moveable at any degree like 30, 40 , or 50 degree either 0 or 90 degree.
i have tried couple of things but they all waorked at giving the blue colored object free roation at any point
can anyone help ?[image]

Comment: Could you accept this: It's possible to turn manually the blue item from 0 to 90 degrees or from 90 to 0 degrees through all intermediate angles, but as soon as one detaches his hand from the blue item it automatically snaps to 0 or 90 degrees depending on which one happens to be closer? Or should all intermediate positions be unreachable even as escorted? BTW The latter is surely something not so usual except in case the blue item is detachable and one plugs it to one of 2 possible sockets.

Comment: look at Lego bricks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a **detent** mechanism.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 3D printed detent mechanism. Image source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnqAtSeqRPo).*

In your case you would need to modify the design for a single 90° detent. To achieve this you may need to make it deeper - say with a 45° slope each side of the mid-position.

Comment: thx body it fixed my problem god bless ur soul

Comment: "body"? If this provides a good answer to your problem then please accept this answer to mark the question as solved.